# python: interrupt odeint when a condition is met

Tags: odeint

I am using odeint function from scipy.integrate package:

```
r0 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
t=np.linspace(0,1,20)
def drdt(r,t):
    return r # or whatever else
r = odeint(drdt,r0,t)
```

r0 is a numpy array that contains the initial positions of a certain number of points.
At the end of the script, as expected, I get the positions of the points at the 20 timestep.

Now I would like to stop the odeint solver when a condition on r is met. In particular I would like to stop odeint when 2 of these points are closer than a certain threshold, make some changes on the r vector, and continue the odeint solver with the new initial positions.
Is there a way to implement this?

A possible solution I have been thinking is to run the odeint to the end, and just later check if the condition was met, but this is of course not very efficient.

Thank you all for the help,
Nicola

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for C++. It's maybe not the best place to post it but it may still be of interest. (I did not find a better place to put it, and this is where I landed when looking for the C++ solution).

Below is a C++ example that stops the integration when the variable gets equal or below zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;


typedef double state_type;

typedef runge_kutta_cash_karp54< state_type > error_stepper_type;


class Myode{
public:
  void operator()(const state_type& x, state_type& dxdt, const double t){dxdt=-1-x;}
  static bool done(const state_type &x){return x<=0.0;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   Myode ode;
   state_type x=10.0;
   auto stepper =  make_controlled< error_stepper_type >( 1.0e-10 , 1.0e-6 );
   auto iter= boost::find_if(make_adaptive_range(stepper,ode,x, 0.0 , 20.0 , 0.01 ),
                 Myode::done);

   cout<<"integration stopped at"<<x<<endl;
  return 1;
}
```

The integration stops the first time it reaches a value x smaller or equal to zero (see done function). So depending on your current step size, it can be quite far below zero.

Note that this uses c++11 constructs, so you need to enable this on you compiler. In my case (gcc 4.4) it was achieved by adding -std=gnu++0x to the compilation command.